# Creating library on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, qt, dylib

I am trying to create a dynamic library on Mac OS X. I use qmake to generate the Makefile for this platform. The dylib builds fine, but it creates the version-specific name and three symlinks with different version specifiers:

- libsimplezip.1.0.0.dylib
- @libsimplezip.1.0.dylib --> libsimplezip.1.0.dylib
- @libsimplezip.1.dylib --> libsimplezip.1.0.0.dylib
- @libsimplezip.dylib --> libsimplezip.1.0.0.dylib

This is the default behavior and I would, maybe, not care, but the problem appears when I try using this library in another project:

```
LIBS += -Lpath/to/lib -lsimplezip
```

Thus Xcode links the library *libsimplezip.dylib*, but in order to run the program, the dynamic library has to be placed inside the bundle. In order to achieve this I use *Copy Files* build phase. Unfortunately, it doesn't work, because Xcode resolves the symlink and copies that only file giving it the same name as symlink, i.e. *libsimplezip.dylib*, while the library's install name is *libsimplezip.1.dylib*. Consequently the program is unable to find the library.

So how is this supposed to be done? Should I change the install name of the library to *libsimplezip.dylib*, so it doesn't have a version specifier? Or should I specify the certain library version like

```
LIBS += -Lpath/to/lib/libsimplezip.1.dylib
```

Or maybe I should somehow disable version specifiers? What is the common way?

Comment: I think I understand the issue.  The solution is `install_name_tool`.

Comment: Umh.... I hoped to avoid it. But how exactly do you suggest to use? Should I change the install name in the library or in the executable file?

Comment: It's a fairly lengthy subject but it's covered well on this site and others.  I would suggest searching.

Comment: Well, I have been searching long and, probably, I could fix it with install_name_tool, but honestly, I believe there must be a better way of doing that. When I run `otool -L` I see other libs with version numbers (like zlib.1.dylib, for example). My lib seems to follow the same name convention. I think version specifier is added on purpose and not just to make programmer's life more difficult. Moreover, adding install_name_tool to qmake project is complicated, because you have to refer to the output file name, which I didn't manage to do. But anyway, your help is appreciated.